# Exclude package-lock.json from GitHub contribution activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

Now that npm v5.0.0 is out, using npm packages auto-generates a `package-lock.json` on `npm install`. In my case, my `package-lock.json` file happens to be close to 10,000 lines of code.

[image: package-lock.json]

Npm also suggests this file should be committed:

> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.

I don't want this file to be included in the line counts for the [contribution activity](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contribution-activity-in-a-repository/) on GitHub.

I've tried setting the files as vendored code in `.gitattributes`, but that only affects the [repository language](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-languages/).

Is there a way to exclude a file from the contribution activity without adding it to `.gitignore`?

Comment: Maybe try marking the file as `binary` in `.gitattributes`. I don't know if Github will respect that.

Comment: I asked GitHub support and at the time of writing this, there is no support for this sort of functionality

Comment: been a bit, but this has been annoying me too, if, you have no care to use it's time travelling magic, can you just delete it from time to time, tell node not to make it?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I had the same idea, just tried it out, no it won't :(

Answer (score 15):

One way to exclude a file from modifying a user's contribution activity is by associating the commit with a placeholder author. This can be done by providing an empty email field `<>` in the `--author` option.

The signature of the `--author` option: `--author="NAME <EMAIL>"`

```
git add package-lock.json
git commit -m 'initial commit' --author='nocontribute <>'
```

[image]

> FOO_AUTHOR committed with REAL_AUTHOR x time ago.

Comment: Awesome idea. Thx!

Comment: This is helpful also for personal private repos of note, for instance when auto-saving Obsidian vaults! Nice trick!

Answer (score -4):

Run

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

to set your account's default identity.

Omit `--global` to set the identity only in this repository.